# if $\lambda \in sp(u)$ why $\lambda \in sp(\phi)$ too?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, spectra

$E$ est un $K-$espace vectoriel de dimension finie $n$ , et u $ \in L(E) $ 
et $\phi$ une application de $L(E)$ vers $L(E)$
et soit $\phi(v)=u \circ v$

Montrons que si  $\lambda \in sp(u)$ alors $\lambda \in sp(\phi)$  ?

soit $\lambda$ une valeure propre de $u$ alors il existe un vecteur non nul de $E$ tel que $u(x)=\lambda  x$

montrer que $\lambda$ est une valeur propre de $\phi$ est equivalent a montrer qu'il existe un endomorphisme $v$ de $L(E)$ telle que $\phi(v)=\lambda v$
plus précisement que pour tout $x \in E$ $\phi(v)(x)=\lambda v(x)$

si on a trouvé un tel endomorphisme alors $\lambda v(x)-(u\circ v) (x)=0$ 
donc $v(x) $ est un vecteur propre de $u$

l'application $v(x)=\lambda x$ si $x$ un vecteur propre de $u$ , $0$ sinon
celle ci n'est pas lineaire.

Comment peut-on trouver un tel endomorphisme $v$ et quelle est sont interpretation matricielle ?

la version anglaise :

$ E$ is a $K- $ finite dimensional vector space$ $n$, and u $\ in L (E) $

and $\phi $ an application of $L (E) $ to $L (E) $

and let $\phi (v) = u \circ v $

Let's show that if $\lambda \in sp (u) $ then $\lambda \in sp (\phi) $?

is $\lambda $ an eigenvalue of $u $ so there is a non-zero vector of $ E $ such that $u (x) = \lambda x $

show that $\lambda $ is an eigenvalue of $\phi $ is equivalent to show that there is an endomorphism $v $ of $ L (E) $ such that $\phi (v) = \lambda v $

more precisely than for all $x \in E $ $ \phi (v) (x) = \lambda v (x)$

if we found such an endomorphism then $\lambda v (x) - (u \circ v) (x) = 0 $

so $v (x) $ is a proper vector of $u $

the application $v (x) = \lambda x $ if $ x$ an eigenvector of $u $, $0 $ otherwise

this one is not linear.

How can we find such an endomorphism $v $ and what is its matrix interpretation?

Comment: comprendez vous Anglais?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom est ce qu'il faut ecrire en anglais ?

Comment: And what means $sp(u)$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde spectre of u

Comment: @DietrichBurde the spectrum of $u$.  "Valuere propre" is an eigenvalue

Comment: Nous devons écrire nos réponses en anglais sur ce site. Cependant, je pourrais aussi inclure une traduction en français.

Comment: @Omnomnomnomais comment les autres peuvent comprendre ma questio ! est ce que je dois la traduire ?

Comment: I don't think we *have* to answer in english: it is the usual common language for most people here. But it has been encouraged to write down in other languages.

Comment: Il serait utile que vous écriviez une traduction de votre question

Comment: @Omnomnomnom its done

Comment: what is the matricirl interpretation of this question ?

Answer (score 1):

My french is pretty weak, but let's see: supppose $\;\lambda\;$ is an eigenvalue of $\;u\;$ , which means there exists $\;0\neq x\in E\;$ s.t. $\;ux=\lambda x\;$ .

Let us take now any basis $\;B\;$ of $\;E\;$ , and define

$$v\in\mathcal L(E)\;,\;\;v(b):=x\,,\,\,\forall\,b\in B$$

and extend to all $\;E\;$  the definition of $\;v\; $by linearity.

Then, for any $\;b\in B\;$ we get:

$$\phi v(b):=u\circ v(b)=u(v(b))=ux=\lambda x=\lambda vb\implies \lambda\in sp\{\phi\}\;$$
...and voilá ! Or not, if I misunderstood the question...

By the way: observe that $\;v\neq 0\;$, meaning: $\;v\;$ is **not** the zero map...

Comment: comment tu peux assurer qu'il existe un $v$ lineaire qui fait associer chaque b à $x$ ?

Comment: @user515918 Because that's the way **I define it** ! Remember that you can  define *any* linear map you want by assigning arbitrary values to some **base** of the linear space...and then extending that definition by linearity.

Comment: cette notion d'extension d'où vient elle ?

Comment: I think that we can say : $v$ est le projecteur de $E $ sur le sous espace des vecteurs propres de u associé à $\lambda$

Comment: No. In fact $\;v\;$ collapses the whole space $\;E\;$ onto the subspace generated by $\;\{x};\$ . There could be other vectors, linearly independent from $\;x\;$ , associated with the eigenvalue $\;\lambda\;$ ...